# Ошибка JUnit version 3.8 or later expected

Tags: android, юнит-тесты, junit

Подключаю библиотеку `JUnit`, когда запускаю тест вылетает ошибка:

> !!! JUnit version 3.8 or later expected:
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!     at
>   junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.(BaseTestRunner.java:5)     at
>   junit.textui.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:54)    at
>   junit.textui.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:48)    at
>   junit.textui.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:41)    at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.junitVersionChecks(JUnitStarter.java:191)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.canWorkWithJUnitVersion(JUnitStarter.java:174)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

`Gradle`:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:3.6'}
```

Класс теста:

```
public class HomeActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<HomeActivity>
{
 private static String TAG = HomeActivityTest.class.getSimpleName();

private HomeActivity mActivity;

public HomeActivityTest(Class<HomeActivity> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass);
}


@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
}


@SmallTest
public void testClickNavigation(){
   // some test
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, там давненько уже есть версии 4.** , может имеет смысл перейти на более свежую версию jUnit? Я например использую версию 4.11
Насколько я понимаю, новая версия jUnit решит Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Такая ошибка может возникать вне зависимости от того, какой JUnit вы используете, даже если у вас JUnit 4.*

1. Убедитесь, что вы проимпортировали JUnit 4. Project Settings ->
   Modules -> Dependencies.
2. В Android Studio создайте конфигурацию Android JUnit или Android Tests. Просто JUnit tests не подходит для андроид приложений. Также
   Android Instrumented Tests не подходят для модульного тестирования,
   т.к. они тестируют на устройстве.
3. В конфигурации JRE укажите  1.* а не Android API ** Platform , т.к. юнит-тесты исполняются на JVM вашего компьютера, а не на устройстве Андроид.
   [image: Настройки конфигурации]
4. И еще проверьте, что у вас build variant выбран debug,  а не release, т.к. тестирование возможно только для сборок в режиме отладки.